Issues with passing a pointer via reference in Cpp
    void insertNodeInternal(int v, Node* &selectedNode){ 
        if (selectedNode == nullptr) { 
            selectedNode = new Node(v);
        }
        else if (v <= selectedNode->GetValue())
            insertNodeInternal(v, selectedNode->GetLeftNode());
        else 
            insertNodeInternal(v, selectedNode->GetRightNode());
    }

The above shown function should add node into a binary tree. The error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue comes up when I am trying to call the insertNodeInternal(v, selectedNode->GetLeftNode()). Same error with the right node.
Node *GetLeftNode (){return this -> left;}
This is the getter for the Node class
Node* left=nullptr;
This is a declaration of left in the Node class
Same error with the selectNode->GetRightNode()
Note that only the selectNode part is underlined in red in my IDE.
Many thanks
It should be a recursive function, used in another function:
    void insertNode (int v){
        this->insertNodeInternal(v, GetRoot());
    }

GetRoot() gets underlined as well
I have looked into passing the argument as pointer to pointer, alas I would prefer it passed as reference.

GetLeftNode() returns by value and your function does not accept that since those are considered temporary objects and a non-const lvalue reference cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

Not your immediate issue, but this is not a valid binary search. If the node to insert has be inserted between two other nodes, this will never happen: you'd get infinite recursion.

Note that even if the compiler accepted this code, it wouldn't do what you want.  GetLeftNode() returns a copy of left, so assigning to it would have no effect on left itself.
